# How can I check Dev vs Prod in Appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How can I write application code to check between AppEngine applications running in development vs running in Production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the enviornmental variable [`SERVER_SOFTWARE`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#detecting_application_runtime_environment)

```
# Check for appengine app identity.
app_env = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', None)
if app_env:
    if app_env.startswith('Google App Engine/'):
        # Appengine Production
        print("Appengine Production Detected")

if app_env.startswith("Development") or app_env.startswith("AppScaleServer"):
    # Dev or appscale env
    print("Local Dev / appscale detected")
else:
    print("app_env not declared")
```